# c++ Remove line from .txt file

Tags: c++, file, line

I'm trying to remove a line from my .txt file. The file contains all the information regarding the account.

The line says "newAccount" and is made when creating the account. I use this so that I can boot up the tutorial when you first log in. After the tutorial I want to remove this line so that in next login you do not get the tutorial.

Heres a snippet of the code: **(doesn't work)**

```
void loginScreen(string user){
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Hello " + user << endl;

    ifstream file(user + ".txt");
    string line1;
    getline(file, line1);
    // Begin reading your stream here
    string line2;
    getline(file, line2);

    if(line2 == "newAccount"){
        cout << "Your account is new";

        char cUser[200];

        strcpy_s(cUser, user.c_str());

        std::ofstream newFile( user + ".txt.new" );
        //  Do output...!!!!!!!
        newFile << line1;
        newFile.close();
        if ( newFile ) {
            remove( cUser + ".txt" );
            rename( cUser + ".txt", cUser + ".txt" );
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Write error on output" << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:

I have edited my code to this and it still does not work:

```
const string oldFileName(user + ".txt");
const string newFileName(user + ".txt.new");

std::ofstream newFile( user + ".txt.new" );
//  Do output...!!!!!!!
newFile << line1;
newFile.close();


if(line2 == "newAccount"){
    ofstream newFile(newFileName.c_str()); // c++11 allows std::string
    if (newFile){
        if (0 == remove( oldFileName.c_str() )){
            if (0 != rename( newFileName.c_str(), oldFileName.c_str() )){
                // Handle rename failure.
            }
        }else{
            // Handle remove failure.
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried to use strcpy(cUser, user.c_str()); but my compiler errored and even recommended me to use strcpy_s

Comment: I rolled back the edit. Editing the question in response to answers is not helpful as it makes current answers unhelpful and confuses people coming to the question later.

Comment: @Hmjd, sorry, I have cut the code from the answer back to the question, without reading all the comments. I think it makes sense there, if subsequential edits are stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
rename( cUser + ".txt", cUser + ".txt" );
```

is incorrect for two reasons:

1. it is pointer arithmetic not string contatenation as `cUser` is a `char[]`
2. even it was correct contatenation the old file name and new file name are the same

There is no reason to be using `strcpy_s()`, use `operator+` for `std::string`:

```
const std::string oldFileName(user + ".txt");
const std::string newFileName(user + ".txt.new");

std::ofstream newFile(newFileName.c_str()); // c++11 allows std::string
if (newFile && newFile << line1)
{
    newFile.close();
    if (newFile)
    {
        if (0 == remove( oldFileName.c_str() ))
        {
            if (0 != rename( newFileName.c_str(), oldFileName.c_str() ))
            {
                // Handle rename failure.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle remove failure.
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to `file.close()` before attempting to `remove()` it.

Always check the result of IO operations, the code does not confirm that if `file` is opened or if any of the `getline()` attempts were successful:

```
ifstream file(user + ".txt");
if (file.is_open())
{
    string line1, line2;
    if (getline(file, line1) && getline(file, line2))
    {
        // Successfully read two lines.
    }
}
```

Comment: I have changed my code to your adjustments, but it is still not working. I've edited my code sample at top.

Comment: The new file does not get filled and the old file doesn't get removed and replaced.

Comment: Suggest checking the opening of the original file and printing the contents to ensure it contains what you expect. Also report any failures with the reason for failure (`errno` for example).

Comment: I've used perror to check what went wrong, but it prints
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe'
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'ConsoleApplication2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe'
The program '[4148] ConsoleApplication2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I also added a cout for each error handle, and it seems that only the removal fails.

Comment: @user2376038, call `file.close()` _before_ attempting to `remove()`.